# "display: table" and "float:left" not respecting margins

Tags: html, css, responsive-design, mobile-safari, chrome-ios

I have a bunch of buttons in a row, with content vertically centered inside:

```
.button {
  width: 18%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: table;
  float: left;
}

.button-inner {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

But for some reason, the buttons don't respect the margins when viewed on mobile browsers (Safari 8 and Chrome 41 on iOS 8.3).

If I change `display: table` to `display: inline-block` then the margins are fine, but then I lose the vertical centering achieved by using `display: table-cell` on `.button-inner`.

(I could vertically center `.button-inner` using the `position: absolute`, but it requires some tweaking across media queries to ensure it centers nicely.)

Any ideas why this margin issue is happening?

Comment: Can we get a fiddle with the actual code? Hard to replicate otherwise. Also, in your `.button` rule, your semicolon after float is actually a colon. So that rule is going to be ignored.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

:) Also don't forget to add vendor prefixes.

```
.button {
  width: 18%;
  margin: 0 1%;
  height: 160px;
  padding: 10px;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  float: left;
}

.button-inner {
  text-align: center;
}
```

Comment: AHH! Thank you! How could I forget about flexbox? Worked perfectly :)